# Rounding a calculation up using php

Tags: php

How would I round this calculation up automatically??

`$calc = (14.3/10)/2.33`   Result = 6.137339055794

The value I would like to have is 6.13

Have searched the site but can't find any answers on this

Comment: That looks truncated, not rounded.

Comment: [Extensive research found this resource](http://bit.ly/1x0loUy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP round().

`$calc = round($calc, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

The result of `(14.3/10)/2.33` is not 6.137339055794. It's 0.6137339055794.

I'm assuming: `$calc = (14.3/10) / 2.33 * 10;`.

The function [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) **rounds half up, half down, half even or half odd** numbers (floating point numbers), but the result of `round($calc, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)` is not  6.13. It's 6.14.

Assuming you'd like to **round down** or **truncate** that number, a solution could be:

```
$truncated = (int)($calc * 100) / 100;
```

or

```
$precision = 2;
$tensPrecision = pow(10, $precision);
$truncated = (int)($calc * $tensPrecision) / $tensPrecision;
```

.

To **round up**, you could do:

```
$truncated = ceil($calc * 100) / 100;
```

or

```
$precision = 2;
$tensPrecision = pow(10, $precision);
$truncated = ceil($calc * $tensPrecision) / $tensPrecision;
```